# How can I reproduce a SSL handshake timeout failure?

Tags: ssl

Is there any mock target than I can hit that just hangs up during an SSL handshake and the connection would then timeout

Comment: No but this is a fantastic suggestion for the folks behind https://badssl.com/

Comment: Ok, i just did it - tracked here: https://github.com/chromium/badssl.com/issues/326

Comment: You don't need a public server for this but can easily do this by your own. Just create a simple TCP server which only accepts a connection and then does nothing, i.e. `nc -l -p 443` or similar. Since it does not do anything after getting the TCP connection the SSL handshake should timeout.

Comment: yeah. I did it in another way. I had a https node server on a docker. Configured iptables on the docker to drop the SYN packets.

Comment: This doesn't cover the scenario where server sends ServerHello and then no longer responds at all. I'm sure there a fuzzying library somewhere that does all this.